# What are all the Infernal Iron locations?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

Without spoiling the story, one potential member of your party needs "Infernal Iron" to repair/improve themselves. I've found some, but as I can be a bit of a completionist, I'd like to find all of them. Or at the very least, ensure I haven't missed any in Act 1 or Act 2 before going to Act 3.

Comment: There are lots of them for sure. I think your best bet is wiki pages for stuff like this, "list requests" don't really work well for this Q&A site.

Comment: [BG3wiki](https://bg3.wiki/wiki/Infernal_Alloy) has a pretty good list -- no clue if it's comprehensive or not, though.

Comment: @RavenDreamer That's Infernal Alloy, Infernal Iron is here: https://bg3.wiki/wiki/Infernal_Iron

Comment: You apparently only need two for the quest. According to the Wiki it can also be looted from specific robotic enemies in Act 3, so you should be able to get way more than the five (Dammon can make equipment from 3 of them) you have a use for.

Comment: Oops! Shared the wrong link. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

**There are 10 pieces of Infernal Iron with fixed locations**, and more can be obtained from destroying Steel Watchers. The ✗ links to the location on the online [Interactive Map](https://mapgenie.io/baldurs-gate-3).

**Act 1**

- [Stonemason Kith](https://baldursgate3.wiki.fextralife.com/Stonemason+Kith) will give you Infernal Iron if you successfully analyse the rocks. ([✗](https://mapgenie.io/baldurs-gate-3/maps/wilderness?locationIds=297560)) (And, unless this has been patched, you can use this single item for three upgrades, see [here](https://baldursgate3.wiki.fextralife.com/Infernal+Iron).)
- In a treasure crate behind Dror Ragzlin's throne in the Shattered Sanctum ([✗](https://mapgenie.io/baldurs-gate-3/maps/wilderness?locationIds=297016))
- In the Zhentarim Hideout ([✗](https://mapgenie.io/baldurs-gate-3/maps/wilderness?locationIds=297025)) (you need to gain access to the room using the Burrow Hole nearby.)
- In the Blighted Village/Whispering Depths, in the locked Blacksmith's room ([✗](https://mapgenie.io/baldurs-gate-3/maps/wilderness?locationIds=297561))

**Act 2**

- In the Gauntlet of Shar, in the Grand Mausoleum, in a chest ([✗](https://mapgenie.io/baldurs-gate-3/maps/shadow-cursed-lands?locationIds=295507))
- In that same area, [Yurgir](https://baldursgate3.wiki.fextralife.com/Yurgir) the Orthon possesses one. You have to kill him to obtain it.
- Outside in the Shadow-Cursed Lands, in the [Masons' Guild in Reithwin](https://baldursgate3.wiki.fextralife.com/Reithwin+Masons%27+Guild) ([✗](https://mapgenie.io/baldurs-gate-3/maps/shadow-cursed-lands?locationIds=295513))

**Act 3**

- Among Big Huido's smuggled goods in Baldur's Gate Lower City ([✗](https://mapgenie.io/baldurs-gate-3/maps/baldurs-gate?locationIds=307407))
- In Flymm's Cargo Basement in Baldur's Gate ([✗](https://mapgenie.io/baldurs-gate-3/maps/baldurs-gate?locationIds=301574))
- When you take the submersible there to Iron Throne, you can find another piece right after you exit (not entirely sure; this might have been patched)
- The [Steel Watchers](https://bg3.wiki/wiki/Steel_Watcher) in the Lower City sometimes drop Infernal Iron.